# Post-apocalyptic story about a girl, her father and an alien attack

Tags: story-identification, aliens, post-apocalyptic

It begins with a planet (Earth or possibly some colony planet) where the humans live underground because there are aliens searching for them.  There is some sort of debris field (possibly ice or rock) or something in a low orbit shielding the planet that makes it difficult for the aliens to find the humans.  There is a young girl (4-5yr old) and her father.  He has a job with other adults charged with detecting alien attack and also defence: they have an underground area with planes or ships separate from where everyone lives.

An alien ship or ships breaks through and finds the humans.  The father tells the girl to run back underground to their home.  She starts to go while the father runs off to join the others in defending the humans with his ship or plane.  She only pretends to go though and comes back to watch the battle.  The humans prevail but something happened during the battle with the dad.  I think he dies, but he is dishonored by the defence people for cowardice or some bizarre behavior during the battle.  He might even have been shot down by friendly forces, I can't recall.  That's what they are saying but the daughter thinks this isn't true.

I think it may be a graphic novel as that's mostly what I've been reading.  But it could also be anime, animated, manga.  I'm pretty sure it wasn't a live action movie, TV or book.  It's fairly recently in my memory, like something I've seen in the past 2-6 months.  I could be wrong about some of the details as my memory is a bit fuzzy about all of it.  I've searched my library reading history and done many internet searches but no luck.

Comment: Welcome, good luck, and you can also check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just rediscovered what this was.  Brandon Sanderson's new book [***Skyward***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36642458-skyward).  I must've read the [free prologue](https://www.gollancz.co.uk/2017/12/18/announcing-brandon-sandersons-skyward/)  and forgot what it was but now I saw the book actually came out and the little blurb jogged my memory.

> ‘Defeated, crushed, and driven almost to extinction, the remnants of
>   the human race are trapped on a planet that is constantly attacked by
>   mysterious alien starfighters.  Spensa, a teenage girl living amongst
>   these last humans, longs to be a pilot and join the fight.  When she
>   discovers the wreckage of an ancient ship, she realizes this dream
>   might be possible …assuming she can repair the ship, navigate flight
>   school, and (perhaps most importantly) persuade the strange machine to
>   help her.  Because this ship, it appears, has a soul.’

Comment: Good job posting the answer to your question.. A lot of people forget to do that.