# Science fiction book in which the Earth was moved and humans are clustered in ghettos throughout the galaxy

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space

My memories are quite vague, but the big central premise is that while humans comprise the majority of the population of the galaxy, they are clustered in ghettos and are not the dominant species. I believe humans or slaves were used as menial workers. There was possibly some kind of revolt. At some point in human history, the Earth was moved and it was known as "the day that the stars changed" or something like that.

I read this my first year of college which would’ve been 85 through 86, I think. No later than 87, but I’m thinking 86.

Comment: Some similarities to this https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228038/novel-about-defeated-humanity-staging-a-comeback-by-discovering-an-ancient-stars

Comment: Classic SF where humans are relegated to ghettos is Knight's *The Earth Quarter*, but IIRC the Earth isn't gone, people just left.  (At the end of the story the aliens are sending all the humans back.)